# Issue with running Bash script in linux.

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh, backtrack-linux

Im having an issue with a bash script i picked up from google code. I have all the dependencies installed and i have it setup to what i think is correct.

To run the code im typing into the console **./jasagerPwn.sh**

The error its saying is

`[!] FATAL: You must run jasagerPwn from inside the directory...`

....WHAT DIRECTORY? I dont know what directory it expects me to run it from?

You can see the script i am using here: http://jasagerpwn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jasagerPwn

Comment: That looks like an awesomely bad script, fyi. It could just `cd $(basename "$0")` and be done. Also, I'm not sure whether it's within the ethics of SO to post network hacking tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the script, it looks in the current dir if you have something matching `jasagerPwn`. If not, the error you was encountering appears.